# Applying Chapman - Kolmogorov to a probability

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

I am answering a practice question, and in the first part I have calculated the 2nd state probabilities of the following transition matrix:
[image]

I caluclated from this **P(X2=j), j=1,2,3,4,5.**

I am now being asked: **P(X2=2,X4=5)**, which I know is equivalent to, **P(X4=5 | X2=2)P(X2=2)**

However this is where I run into trouble, my solution tells me I can write:

**P(X4=5 | X2=2)P(X2=2)** = **P(X2=5 | X0=2)P(X0=2)**

I know the Chapman Kolmogorov proof, but I don't understand how to apply it here? Or do I need to use another theorem.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_2=2,X_4=5) &= \mathbb P(X_4=5\mid X_2=2)\mathbb P(X_2=2)\\
&= P^2_{2,5} + \mathbb P(X_2=2\mid X_0=1)\mathbb P(X_0=1) + \mathbb P(X_2=2\mid X_0=5)\mathbb P(X_0=5)\\
&= P_{2,5}^2 + P_{1,2}^2\cdot\frac 12 + P^2_{2,5}\cdot\frac12.
\end{align}
Computing $P^2$, we have

$$
P^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{29}{100} & \frac{3}{25} & \frac{7}{50} & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{3}{20} \\
 0 & \frac{13}{25} & 0 & \frac{11}{25} & \frac{1}{25} \\
 \frac{13}{50} & \frac{4}{25} & \frac{4}{25} & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{3}{25} \\
 \frac{3}{50} & \frac{11}{25} & \frac{3}{100} & \frac{21}{50} & \frac{1}{20} \\
 \frac{3}{25} & \frac{1}{25} & \frac{3}{25} & \frac{7}{20} & \frac{37}{100} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and thus
$$
\mathbb P(X_2=2,X_4=5) = \frac1{25} + \frac3{50} + \frac1{50} =\frac3{25}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, would our answer not be (22,5)(P(X2=2))= 0.04 * 0.08 = 0.00032?

Comment: Sorry I mean 0.0032